# Question on surjection of function into set of equivalence classes

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I am attempting this proof by giving a guess that I believe is incorrect. Can I get a few hints on approaching the surjection proof?

Suppose that $f:A \rightarrow B$.Define a relation $R$ on $A$ by $xRy$ iff $f(x)=f(y)$

Problem:For any $x \in A$ let $E_x$ be the equivalence class of $x$.

That is $E_x=\{y \in A : yRx\}$

Let E be the collection of all equivalence classes.

That is $E=\{E_x:x \in A\}$

Prove that the function $g:A \rightarrow E$ defined by

$g(x)=E_x$ is surjective.

Attempt:

Since $ \bigcup\limits_ {x \in A}E_x=A$.Then for all $y\in E_x$, there exists $x \in A$ s.t. $g(x)=y$ so $g$ is surjective.

Comment: The step "Since $\bigcup_ {x \in A}E_x=A$, then for all $y\in E_x$, there exists $x \in A$ such that $g(x)=y$" doesn't seem sound to me: the first statement doesn't mention the function $g$ at all, but a conclusion is being drawn about $g$. I recommend showing how $\bigcup_ {x \in A}E_x=A$ is related to the function $g$.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is a little garbled, though I don't believe you're far off. Note that, if you let $y \in E_x$, then $y \in A$, not $B$. That is, $y$ is an element of the domain!

You need to start by assuming you have an arbitrary element $Y$ in the codomain of $g$, i.e. $E$. That is, by definition of $E$, we have $Y = E_a$ for some $a \in A$. Note that, by definition of $g$, we have $g(a) = E_a = Y$.

That is, given any $Y$ in the codomain of $g$, there exists an $a$ in the domain of $g$, such that $g(a) = Y$. This means $g$ is surjective.

Comment: So I can just say let $y \in E$ then $y=E_a$ for some $a \in A$ so for all $y \in E$ there exists $a \in A$ s.t. $g(a)=E_a=y$ and that completes the proof?

Comment: @Eastcoastdancer That's right. I only used a capital $Y$ to fit in with the convention of using capital letters for sets. But, in addition to being a set, it is an element of our codomain $E$. If you wish to call it $y$ instead of $Y$, then please do so.

Comment: ok since the convention is to use capital letters

Answer (score 0):

You have used x twice to mean two different things at for all x,.. there exists a x.. .
Assume C in E.  Thus exists x in A with C = E$_x$.
Consequently, g(x) = C.